# repaint Tab-Control empty Tab Space

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

In WinForms, how do I repaint the empty area that contains empty tab space to be filled by new tabs in a color of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in winforms.  The tabcontrol background property (as opposed to tabpage background) **might** do it.

Of course, it's worth mentioning that you can style **anything** in WPF, if you end up going that way.

Comment: do you mean this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4sc610z.aspx - but then how do I override that property? I am not planning going the wpf route but the telerik rad controls for winforms route as well as the diy route for where the rad controls are too slow in repainting something